# How can I run SysInternals ProcMon (or equivalent) inside a docker Windows container?

Tags: sysinternals, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to diagnose an issue where a complicated process does not run inside of my Windows Core container. I really need to figure out why it is failing. If this was a VM, I would just pop up the procmon GUI and easily diagnose what files it's looking for but aren't there, but in docker, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process Monitor can be run without GUI to a log file.

Use the parameter `backingfile`, and do not forget on first usage to also
include the `accepteula` parameter.

You may use the Docker parameter of `-v` (-volume) to share a host folder,
where you may store the Process Monitor release files and the resulting
log file.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because is answer on my question. But it seems not work in the docker for windows. If anyone come across this post, look [here](https://forum.sysinternals.com/procmon-in-windows-containers_topic32977.html).
I still have not found a solution to the problem.

Comment: Another [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b20be612-95da-4476-8b15-) says it might work for containers using Hyper-V isolation. You could also try to add the switches `/Quiet /Minimized`.

Comment: I did this: `procmon.exe /AcceptEula /Quiet /Minimized /BackingFile c:\temp\log.pml`

Comment: I saw the post about Hyper-V. I don't know for sure if it using Hyper-V but I'm pretty sure that it has a separate kernel. 
Thanks anyway and if you will find something I'd love to know.

Comment: It should be using Hyper-V by default, unless you changed it by right-click on the docker icon and then on "Switch to Windows containers". You may also ask on the [sysinternals forums](https://forum.sysinternals.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I changed it to "Switch to Windows Container".

Answer (score 0):

`procmon` doesn't work on servercore Docker image. You should simply run it on the Host and it will be able to see what you need.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180951)